# Putting guessed letters instead of dashes / Hangman / Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

i made hangman and am using this code. everything works fine, i just want to replace dashes in the list [lenghtDashes] with the correctly guessed letter in the corresponding place. i could not find any information online or here as well. maybe someone knows.
im open to any improvement suggestions as well.

```
secWord = input("What is the word for others to guess?: ")
life = 10
#starting information

i = 1
while i < 10:
    print(".")
    i += 0.01
#dots so players can not see the word

print("you have 10 tries to guess the word")
print("you will have to choose between gessing a letter (l) or a word (w) in start of every turn")
print("however, if you guess the word incorrectly you will lose immediately")
ans = input("are you ready to begin?: ")
while ans != "yes":
    ans = input("now? ")
#rules

i = 1
while i < 10:
    print(".")
    i += 0.01
#dots for taking players to start

lenghtDashes = []
for letter in range(len(secWord)):
    lenghtDashes.append("_")
#making dashes list

print("let's begin")
print("the word has " + str(len(secWord)) + " letters.")
appended = "".join(lenghtDashes)
print(appended)
#info for players

usedLetters = []
guessedLetters = []
wordLis = []



while life > 0 and ans != secWord:
    print("are you guessing letter or a word?")
    guessThing = input("l / w : ")

    #for guessing a word
    if guessThing == "w":
        ans = input("What is the secret word?: ")

        if ans == secWord:
            print("Congratulations, you have guessed the right word\nYou won!")

        else:
            print("You guessed the word incorrectly\n The word was " + secWord + " \n You lost!")
            exit()
#=================================================================
    #for guessing a letter
    elif guessThing == "l":
        letList = [letter for letter in secWord]

        guLett = input("Guess the letter \n(single letter only): ")

        usedLetters.append(guLett)

        if guLett in letList:
            guessedLetters.append(guLett)
            letListPlus = [letter for letter, x in enumerate(letList) if x == guLett]
            letListPlusPlus = [num + 1 for num in letListPlus]

            print("///")
            print("///")
            print("///")

            print("Letters that you have used : " + str(usedLetters))
            print("Letter that are correct: " + str(guessedLetters))
            print("The position of letter " + str(guLett) + " is " + str(letListPlusPlus))

        else:

            print("///")
            print("///")
            print("///")

            print("incorrect guess, you have " + str(life - 1) + " guesses remaining")
            life = life - 1
            print("Letters that you have used are: " + str(usedLetters))
            print("Letter that are correct: " + str(guessedLetters))

#=================================================================
```

Comment: If you want improvement suggestions, you could try the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you need your in-progress word to be displayed (like `"o_e_f_ow"`), call this function:

```
def wordWithDashes(guessedLetters, letList):
    return [letter if letter in guessedLetters else "_" for letter in letList]
```

It creates a new list from `letList` with missing letters replaced with `"_"`. You can use `str` on it if you want a string result.

You don't need to keep track of `lenghtDashes`. Just compute it from the guessed letters and the actual word whenever you need it, as the code I provided does.